# PySpark, count days between two dates

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with columns ***[date, time, ad_id]***, where ad_id - advert id. I need to calculate the number of days the ad was shown (in other words calculate duration between rows grouped by ad_id) and add this new column to dataframe. 
What function should i use better?

Comment: `groupby` and `lag`

Comment: please provide sample reproducible data , with expected out, to encourage people to respond.